# For loop, Multiple counters

Tags: c#

I was wondering if the following pseudo code could be achieved somehow. I have 4 lists with indexes of different sizes so can't use the same reference counter. I need to run the four at the same time so that I can add the details to the datagridview in one row.

```
            for (int m = 0, n = 0, p = 0, q = 0; m <= coords_Count, n <= outer_plf_Count, p <= planet_start_plf_Countt, q <= planet_plf_Count, m++, n++, p++, q++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                block_coords_list[m][(int)Coords.X],        //Column 1
                block_coords_list[m][(int)Coords.Y],        //Column 2
                block_coords_list[m][(int)Coords.Z],        //Column 3
                outer_plf_list[n][(int)Outer_plf.Hash],     //Column 4
                outer_plf_list[n][(int)Outer_plf.X],        //Column 5
                outer_plf_list[n][(int)Outer_plf.Y],        //Column 6
                outer_plf_list[n][(int)Outer_plf.Z],        //Column 7
                outer_plf_list[n][(int)Outer_plf.OrbitName],        //Column 8
                outer_plf_list[n][(int)Outer_plf.PrefabName],       //Column 9
                planet_start_plf_list[p][(int)Planet_Start_plf.X],  //Column 10
                planet_start_plf_list[p][(int)Planet_Start_plf.Y],  //Column 11
                planet_start_plf_list[p][(int)Planet_Start_plf.Z],  //Column 12
                planet_start_plf_list[p][(int)Planet_Start_plf.PlanetName],  //Column 13
                planet_start_plf_list[p][(int)Planet_Start_plf.PlanetBiome], //Column 14
                planet_start_plf_list[p][(int)Planet_Start_plf.StartTrue],   //Column 15
                planet_plf_list[q][(int)Planet_plf.X],      //Column 16
                planet_plf_list[q][(int)Planet_plf.Y],      //Column 17
                planet_plf_list[q][(int)Planet_plf.Z],      //Column 18
                planet_plf_list[q][(int)Planet_plf.PlanetaryBodyName],   //Column 19
                planet_plf_list[q][(int)Planet_plf.PrefabName]);         //Column 20
            }
```

Comment: I don't think you need four counters.  I mean, you're incrementing the counters in the same way every time you loop, so you could probably get by with a single one.  Am I missing some detail of your implementation?

Comment: If i increment them all using the same counter i will get an exception because some of  the index have a length of 4 and some of 8 and some 6. In my datagrid i just fill these with empty spaces if there is no data

Comment: If the indexes have different maximums the for loop will still run until **all** indexes have reached their maximum...  Having 4 or having 1, your code does the same thing.  You'll still get an IndexOutOfRange...  Review your logic.

Comment: instead of different counters (which will not work), use Math.Min(counter, x) where x put the maximum value acceptable for the item

Comment: @Gusman I am unfamilair with that but I shall go and look into it.

Comment: @RyanWalkowski Personally, I'd just create the indices before the loop and use them within it.  You're also going to need to add some checks to make sure the index of each one doesn't surpass the maximum of the given row/column, and only exit once all of the indices reach their aforementioned maximums.

Comment: @kondrak I was aware of the checks issue but my methodology is one of lots of trial and error :)  I'll take it under advisement. Would it be too much to ask for a snippet of an example

Comment: @Dai seems to have a functional example below that looks ok.  I think there might be some bigger problems in your program if you're having to write logic that is this repetitive.  I'd seriously consider looping over this 2D array in a different way, unless you're having to work around some pre-existing, poorly constructed, code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, though you need to think about how you want the range to work when it reaches the end of a single source array if the source arrays have different lengths.

The best approach is to have a single `condition` that goes for the longest array, and use the ternary operator `?:` in each column to avoid accessing anything if it's outside that column's data range:

```
int a0Max = block_coords_list.Length;
int a1Max = outer_plf_list.Length;
int a2Max = planet_start_plf_list.Length;
int a3Max = planet_plf_list.Length;
int max = new Int32[] { a0Max, a1Max, a2Max, a3Max }.Max();

for (int i = 0; i < max, i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
        i < a0Max ? block_coords_list[i][(int)coords.X] : null,
        i < a0Max ? block_coords_list[i][(int)coords.Y] : null,
        i < a0Max ? block_coords_list[i][(int)coords.Z] : null, 
        i < a1Max ? outer_plf_list[i][(int)outer_plf.Hash] : null,
        i < a1Max ? outer_plf_list[i][(int)outer_plf.X] : null,
        i < a1Max ? outer_plf_list[i][(int)outer_plf.Y] : null,
        i < a1Max ? outer_plf_list[i][(int)outer_plf.Z] : null,
        i < a1Max ? outer_plf_list[i][(int)outer_plf.OrbitName] : null,
        i < a1Max ? outer_plf_list[i[(int)outer_plf.PrefabName] : null,
        i < a2Max ? planet_start_plf_list[i][(int)planet_Start_plf.X] : null,
        i < a2Max ? planet_start_plf_list[i][(int)planet_Start_plf.Y] : null,
        i < a2Max ? planet_start_plf_list[i][(int)planet_Start_plf.Z] : null,
        i < a2Max ? planet_start_plf_list[i][(int)planet_Start_plf.PlanetName] : null,
        i < a2Max ? planet_start_plf_list[i][(int)planet_Start_plf.PlanetBiome] : null,
        i < a2Max ? planet_start_plf_list[i][(int)planet_Start_plf.StartTrue] : null,
        i < a3Max ? planet_plf_list[i][(int)planet_plf.X] : null,
        i < a3Max ? planet_plf_list[i][(int)planet_plf.Y] : null,
        i < a3Max ? planet_plf_list[i][(int)planet_plf.Z] : null,
        i < a3Max ? planet_plf_list[i][(int)planet_plf.PlanetaryBodyName] : null,
        i < a3Max ? planet_plf_list[i][(int)planet_plf.PrefabName]
    );
}
```

Comment: Your above code is all new to me but very interesting. Thanks for exposing me to this. I'll need to read up on this more to understand it fully.

Comment: @Dai I'd suggest moving the ternary check to a private method to avoid a bit of the verbosity.  Best to perpetuate good coding practices ;)

Comment: @kondrak Moving the ternary to a function would make it uglier, as we don't want eager-evaluation of arguments (which would cause a bounds exception) nor the overhead of lambda invocation (the only way to avoid eager-evaluation at present).